# DataRepeater without subcontrols

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding

What is the right way to do this in a datarepeater control?

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <strong><%= Eval("FullName") %></strong><br />
                <p>
                <%= Eval("Summary") %>
                </p>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Getting error *Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.*

I'd like to just write out the FullName and Summary. But I don't want to nest subcontrols.
Is Repsonse.Write the best way?

**UPDATE**:
Not sure if this is necessary, but the only way I was able to solve it was with  controls

Comment: Are you missing Repeater1.DataSource and Repeater1.DataBind() in your code?

Comment: Nope. Nothing wrong in the CodeBehind.

Answer (score 3):

The repeater requires a datasource, assigned like so:

```
public class Foo
{
public string FullName { get;set; } 
public string Summary {get;set; }

public Foo(fullName,summary)
{
  FullName=fullName;
  Summary=summary;
}
}

/// elsewhere...
List<Foo> myFoos = new List<Foo>();
myFoos.Add(new Foo("Alice","Some chick"));
myFoos.Add(new Foo("Bob","Some guy"));
myFoos.Add(new Foo("Charlie","Indeterminate"));
Repeater1.DataSource = myFoos;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

As this example shows, your datasource can be anything that implements IEnumerable - lists are my favorites, but most collections in C# fall into this category. Your datasource does *not* have to come from a database or anywhere particular.

You don't have to use response.write, or subcontrols. (server controls aren't valid inside of a repeater, anyway). You might try replacing

```
<%=Eval("...
```

with

```
<%#Eval("...
```

I'm unsure of the difference, but the second form is used in most examples.

Comment: Replacing <%= with <%# will solve the problem.  If the control doesn't have a datasource it just won't output anything.

Comment: with <%=Eval I get the error - Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.  

with <%# Argument type System.String is not assignable to parameter type string.
weird

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the follow:

```
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullName") %>
```

Comment: That gives me an error. You can't use the DataBinder outside of a DataBound control?

Comment: Are you not binding your repeater to a datasource somewhere?